# Searching strings in sql Column and need to split required string with prefix

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-function

I have a table and having two columns  account and rt_exclude.I need to select only the word "exclusion" from the   rt_exclude column with the prefix.The rt_exclude column contains many rows with different length so i dont want to use case statement.

```
123 ,      278-C Share Exclusion; 3405-B Share Exclusion; 5784-Reit Exclusion
333 ,    278-C Share Exclusion; 3405-B Share Exclusion; 5784-Reit Exclusion; 6532-Exclude GIREX 39822J102
444,         3274-TSSAX Exclusion; 3370-BFAFX Exclusion; 3405-B Share Exclusion; 5784-Reit Exclusion
```

Required out put should be like this with the account column

```
123,    Share Exclusion
123,   Share Exclusion
123,   Reit Exclusion
333,    Share Exclusion
333,    Share Exclusion
123,    Reit Exclusion
444,   TSSAX Exclusion
444,   BFAFX Exclusion
444,   Reit Exclusion
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like `string_split()`:

```
select t.col1, s.value
from t cross apply
     string_split(col2, '; ') s
where s.value like '%Exclusion';
```

Note that storing multiple values in a single column is discouraged.  You should reconsider the data model.

Comment: string_split is not working in my sql server version.Is there any other way for doing this.Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL Server 2016+ use string_split as suggested.
Getting this done in SQL Server 2014 and below you need a custom split function, e.g. dbo.SplitStrings_CTE from [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string) on SO.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_CTE
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS @Items TABLE (Item NVARCHAR(4000))
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @ll INT = LEN(@List) + 1, @ld INT = LEN(@Delimiter);
 
   WITH a AS
   (
       SELECT
           [start] = 1,
           [end]   = COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, 
                       @List, 1), 0), @ll),
           [value] = SUBSTRING(@List, 1, 
                     COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, 
                       @List, 1), 0), @ll) - 1)
       UNION ALL
       SELECT
           [start] = CONVERT(INT, [end]) + @ld,
           [end]   = COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, 
                       @List, [end] + @ld), 0), @ll),
           [value] = SUBSTRING(@List, [end] + @ld, 
                     COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, 
                       @List, [end] + @ld), 0), @ll)-[end]-@ld)
       FROM a
       WHERE [end] < @ll
   )
   INSERT @Items SELECT [value]
   FROM a
   WHERE LEN([value]) > 0
   OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
 
   RETURN;
END
GO
```

And the selection becomes

```
SELECT t.id
    ,SUBSTRING(s.Item, PATINDEX('%[^0-9- ]%', s.Item)+1, LEN(s.Item)) AS col
FROM docs t
CROSS APPLY SplitStrings_CTE(content, ';') s
WHERE s.Item LIKE '%Exclusion';
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
Select res.col1,   SUBSTRING(res.col2,CHARINDEX('-',res.col2)+CHARINDEX(' ',res.col2),99)
from 
(
select StringSplit.col1, value col2
from  StringSplit
Cross Apply  STRING_SPLIT(StringSplit.col2,';') as ss
WHERE StringSplit.col2 LIKE '%Exclu%') as res
```